# Apply a set of lines to a template

Tags: vim

I want to process a set of lines and apply a template to each line. Let's say I have the following block of lines:

```
CASE
ESAC
IF
FI
```

And I would like to get the following output:

```
<YYINITIAL> {CASE} {
    return new Symbol(sym.CASE);
}

...

<YYINITIAL> {FI} {
    return new Symbol(sym.FI);
}
```

So, I thought of having a template with the body to apply for each line, something like this:

```
<YYINITIAL> {###PLACE_HOLDER###} {
    return new Symbol(sym.###PLACE_HOLDER###);
}
```

And apply it to each line.

What I thought was of selecting the lines, putting then in a register ("a, for instance), then selecting the template putting it in a register ("b) and call an external script that generates the output. However no luck (don't know how to pass the contents of a register to an external script).

Any other approach is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this command will do that job:

```
:%s/.*/<YYINITIAL> {&} {\r\treturn new Symbol(sym.&);\r}/
```

you could remove the `%`, if you visual selected lines. Also you could create a mapping or user command for it, if it is used often.

Comment: Thanks, that was simple and elegant. Didn't know about '&'.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested approach seems overly complex, especially because you still have to implement the template expansion logic as the external script.

Why don't you simply define your templates as `:substitute` commands?! You can pattern-match your `PLACEHOLDER` via `/\({pattern}\)/` and insert it in the replacement text as `\1`, `\2`, etc. (I hope you know about the power of Vim's `:substitute` command; otherwise, read `:help :s`.

You can keep and persist your templates in several ways, depending on how often / long you need them:

1. Just in the command-line history (`:s<Up>`)
2. Save in named registers (`:let @a = @:`), execute with `:@a`
3. Save in a Vim script and `:source` it
4. Write a custom plugin with `:command`s

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It didn't cross my mind to use :s, I agree my approach was much more complex :)